# How to detect spaces in NotePad ++ Version 6.9.2

Tags: sql, notepad++, truncation

01  39  047901  11  09  000011

I may be using an old version. How does one detect the space that is found at the end of this string. I use CTRL+H and enter a space in the "Find What" and nothing in the "Replace With" and it returns that no changes were made. However, I will go to the row that SQL Express says is incompatible and there is a space at the end of the sixth field

I am attempting to import this flat file into SQL Express and it returns a truncation error.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: That is very hard to guess since the string is probably reformatted is I can only guess: Could that be a tab at the end of line? If you are unsure use a hex editor to look at the file content.

Comment: View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters.

Comment: Mrogers,

Thanks, that seems to have solved it. I was trying to do a find and replace and was getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Searching with a space only would do the work.

Hit CTRL+F--> Put a blank in 'Find What'(Hit spacebar from keyboard)--> Enter